# oracle function and cursor using dynamic table name

Tags: oracle11g

IN my oracle database i want to create a function or procedure with cursor which will use dynamic  table name.here is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function Findposition ( model_in IN varchar2,model_id IN number) RETURN number IS cnumber number;
TYPE c1 IS REF CURSOR;
c2 c1;
BEGIN
open c2 FOR 'SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id) AS rownumber FROM '||model_in;
FOR employee_rec in c2
LOOP
    IF employee_rec.id=model_id then
    cnumber :=employee_rec.rownumber;
    end if;
END LOOP;
close c2;
RETURN cnumber;
END;
```

help me to solve this problem.IN

Comment: What is your problem? Do you get errors? And rowid is reserved in oracle, use some other alias name.

Comment: I got error employee_rec not defiend.now i edit in my code, i declare TYPE employee_rec IS REF CURSOR; but after that it shows "Invalid reference to variable 'employee_rec '"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no need to declare a `c1` type for a weakly typed ref cursor.  You can just use the `SYS_REFCURSOR` type.
- You can't mix implicit and explicit cursor calls like this.  If you are going to `OPEN` a cursor, you have to `FETCH` from it in a loop and you have to `CLOSE` it.  You can't `OPEN` and `CLOSE` it but then fetch from it in an implicit cursor loop.
- You'll have to declare a variable (or variables) to fetch the data into.  I declared a record type and an instance of that record but you could just as easily declare two local variables and `FETCH` into those variables.
- `ROWID` is a reserved word so I used `ROWPOS` instead.

Putting that together, you can write something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE OR REPLACE Function Findposition (
  2      model_in IN varchar2,
  3      model_id IN number)
  4    RETURN number
  5  IS
  6    cnumber number;
  7    c2      sys_refcursor;
  8    type result_rec is record (
  9      id      number,
 10      rowpos  number
 11    );
 12    l_result_rec result_rec;
 13  BEGIN
 14    open c2 FOR 'SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id) AS rowpos FROM '||model_in;
 15    loop
 16      fetch c2 into l_result_rec;
 17      exit when c2%notfound;
 18      IF l_result_rec.id=model_id
 19      then
 20        cnumber :=l_result_rec.rowpos;
 21      end if;
 22    END LOOP;
 23    close c2;
 24    RETURN cnumber;
 25* END;
SQL> /

Function created.
```

I believe this returns the result you expect

```
SQL> create table foo( id number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo
  2    select level * 2
  3      from dual
  4   connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> select findposition( 'FOO', 8 )
  2    from dual;

FINDPOSITION('FOO',8)
---------------------
                    4
```

Note that from an efficiency standpoint, you'd be much better off writing this as a single SQL statement rather than opening a cursor and fetching every row from the table every time.  If you are determined to use a cursor, you'd want to exit the cursor when you've found the row you're interested in rather than continuing to fetch every row from the table.

From a code clarity standpoint, many of your variable names and data types seem rather odd.  Your parameter names seem poorly chosen-- I would not expect `model_in` to be the name of the input table, for example.  Declaring a cursor named `c2` is also problematic since it is very non-descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, you don't need loop when you are using dynamic query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function Findposition(model_in IN varchar2,model_id IN number) 
RETURN number IS 
cnumber number;
TYPE c1 IS REF CURSOR;
c2 c1;
BEGIN
open c2 FOR 'SELECT rownumber 
             FROM (
            SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id) AS rownumber 
            FROM '||model_in || ' 
                  ) WHERE id = ' || model_id;

FETCH c2 INTO cnumber;
close c2;

return cnumber;
END;
```