# Pl sql cursor with parameter in condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

Let’s say I have a procedure with a user input parameter.

```
Create procedure Match_Record(v_match_ID)

Cursor match is
Select *
From table A
Where not exists(select ‘bbb’ from table B
                              Where a. v_match_ID = b. v_match_ID);
```

It won’t compile because v_match_ID is not a valid identifier.

So is execute immediate the only option here?

Comment: Are you trying to pass in a column name or a literal here? If `V_MATCH_ID` is a column name then yes, you'll need to use execute immediate (or DBMS_SQL).

Comment: @Ben yes, I’m trying to pass a column name.

Comment: I don't know what question to close this as a duplicate of because there are so many things you might be doing but here are some relevant ones: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12956627/458741, https://stackoverflow.com/q/15786953/458741, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25182858/458741

Answer (score 2):

> "I’m trying to pass a column name"

In which case, yes, you need to use dynamic SQL. Rather than `execute immediate` probably you need to open a cursor variable.

```
Create procedure Match_Record(v_match_ID)
    ... 
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for 
        'Select *
         From table A
         Where not exists(select blah from table B
                           Where a.'||v_match_ID||' = b.'|| v_match_ID||')';
```